# Where does vagrant store generated keys?

Tags: ubuntu, backup, vagrant

By default vagrant generated keys to replace the insecure one.

However I have no idea where they're stored, and I'm trying to back them up.

Where are they stored? (On Ubuntu 20.04)

Comment: All its internal housekeeping is typically stored under `~/.vagrant.d/`, try looking there

Comment: @poige unless it's putting it under a file I'm unaware of the name of I saw nothing that jumped out at me there

Comment: then check the dir with `Vagrantfile`, mine has `./.vagrant/machines/…boxName…/…provider…/private_key`